# Eliminating a call to MainEvaluate from a compiled function

Tags: compile

I would like to write a compile function

```
cf = 
  Compile[{{tracefab, _Complex, 1}}, 
    Module[{fab, i, j},
      fab = Table[0., {i, 1, 5, 1}, {j, 1, 5, 1}];
      For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++,
        For[j = 1, j <= 5, j++,
           fab[[i, j]] = tracefab[[i]];];];
      fab]];
```

However, by using `CompilePrint` I found that the compiled function calls `MainEvluate`,

```
18  C0 = Part[ T(C1)0, I7]
19  V17T(R2)2I7I2 = MainEvaluate[Function[{tracefab, fabCompile$322, iCompile$323, jCompile$324}, Block[{fab = fabCompile$322, i = iCompile$323, j = jCompile$324}, {fab[[i,j]] = tracefab[[i]], fab, i, j}]][ T(C1)0, T(R2)2, I7, I2]]
20  I5 = I2
```

Is there a way to avoid calling Mainevaluate in my case?

Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: Use `fab = Table[0. I, {i, 5}, {j, 5}]` instead so that the type is not being coerced from real to complex.

Comment: It works finally!!! Thank you very much!  @Carl Woll!